# Erro "take not arguments" em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estava fazendo uns teste de tela de login mas sempre da um erro falando que não tem argumentos e a minha tela de login fica sem a parte de digitar o usuario e senha só mostra a janela, e olhaei e todos os nomes estão escritos da mesma forma[image: a descrição do erro]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from tkinter import*

class Principal: #cria a classe principal
    def _init_(self, master=None):
        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial","10")
        self.Container1 = Frame(master)
        self.Container1["pady"]=10
        self.Container1["bg"]="light green"
        self.Container1.pack()

    self.Container2 = Frame(master)
    self.Container2["padx"]=20
    self.Container2["bg"]="light green"
    self.Container2.pack()

    self.Container3 = Frame(master)
    self.Container3["padx"]=20
    self.Container3["bg"]="light green"
    self.Container3.pack()

    self.Container4 = Frame(master)
    self.Container4["pady"]=20
    self.Container4["bg"]="light green"
    self.Container4.pack()

    self.titulo = Label(self.Container1, text="Dados do usuário:")
    self.titulo["font"] = ("Arial","10","bold")
    self.titulo["bg"]="light green"
    self.titulo.pack()

    self.nomeLabel = Label(self.Container2, text="Nome:", font=self.fontePadrao)
    self.nomeLabel["bg"]="light green"
    self.nomeLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.nome = Entry(self.Container2)
    self.nome.focus()
    self.nome["width"]=30
    self.nome["font"] = self.fontePadrao
    self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.senhaLabel = Label(self.Container3, text="Senha:", font=self.fontePadrao)
    self.senhaLabel["bg"]="light green"
    self.senhaLabel.pack(side=LEFT) #kkkk

    self.senha = Entry(self.Container3)
    self.senha["width"]=30
    self.senha["font"] = self.fontePadrao
    self.senha["show"] = "*"
    self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)


    self.autentificar = Button(self.Container4)
    self.autentificar["text"] = "AUTENTIFICAR"
    self.autentificar["font"] = ("Calibri","10","bold")
    self.autentificar["width"] = 12
    self.autentificar["bg"] = "white"
    self.autentificar["command"] = self.verificaSenha
    self.autentificar.pack()

    self.sair = Button()
    self.sair["text"] = "SAIR"
    self.sair["font"] = ("Calibri","10","bold")
    self.sair["width"] = 5
    self.autentificar["command"] = quit
    self.sair.pack(side=TOP)

    self.mensagem = Label(self.Container4, text="",font=self.fontePadrao)
    self.mensagem["bg"] = "light green"
    self.mensagem.pack()


def verificaSenha(self):
    usuario = self.nome.get()
    senha = self.senha.get()

    if usuario == "Rafael" and senha =="123456789":
        self.mensagem["text"]="Autentificado!"
        self.nome["fg"]="gray"
        self.senha["fg"]="gray"
        self.sair.focus_force()
    else:
        self.mensagem["text"] = "Usuário e/ou senha incorretos!"
        self.senha.delete(0,END)
        self.nome.delete(0,END)
        self.nome.focus()



tela = Tk()
tela.title("TELA DE LOGIN")
tela["bg"] = "light green"
tela.geometry("400x250")
Principal(tela)
tela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio eu que o erro no seu código seja apenas a função "init". Ela está apenas com 1 underline em cada lado.

O construtor de classes no Python é o `__init__`.

Edit1:

Por volta da linha 45, há um erro no pack do container.

```
self.senha = Entry(self.Container3)
self.senha["width"]=30
self.senha["font"] = self.fontePadrao
self.senha["show"] = "*"
self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)                    <----- Deveria ser self.senha.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: Achava que era apenas uma underline de cada lado, e nem vi o erro da linha 45 rs muito obrigado esta tudo certo agora